# Assigning child listview more height than its parent height

Tags: android, listview, material-design

I have been working on a layout in which I have to animate the list view in the parent view fragment. When I animate the list view I just have to use the translate animation due to which listview height remain the same and it show an empty area below it if I translate it toward screen top or bottom. Here is the animation code I am using. `animate(mLvLiveFeed).setDuration(500).x(0).y(0));`
It nineold animation library for animation.

What i want is to make the list view height more than parent height so its does not show empty area with it. How can I give listview more height than Match Parent.

Here is the picture of what I want.[image]

Comment: post your layout xml

Comment: its just a simple listview in a relative layout.@MuhammadBabar

Comment: post your animation code.

Comment: just set as match parent, if list goes long then it will show scroll view

Comment: @Gauarav scroll is not issue data is also not issue I want listview size more than the height of Match Parent

Answer (score 0):

Finally I give my view more height than Match Parent of the parent view By giving the required layout bottom margin in -ve value.